# Random value from two different regular expression from same request and that random value's should not be same

Tags: regex, jmeter, performance-testing

Suppose there is a list of id's (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) in http request and I'm using regular extractor to extract them and entered 0 for a random match

I need to pick two values randomly but that should not be picked same otherwise script will fail.

I'm using two regular expression to pick two values from them, but due to random, it is picking same value in both,

I want them different in the same thread as I need to enter those values in url in same thread.
How this can be handle and I have tried with while controller as well but it will keeps on going indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSR223 Sampler with getting different random number by removing it from list:

```
ArrayList<Integer> items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];
log.info("1:" + items.remove(new Random().nextInt(items.size())));
log.info("2:" + items.remove(new Random().nextInt(items.size())));
```

You can add to JMeter variable as

```
vars.put("MyVar", items.remove(new Random().nextInt(items.size())) as String);
```

Comment: List of id's will not remain same and it may be more than 20. Id's will be dynamic as well.So I think this solution will not work. Thanks in Advance
Can there be a solution if random values picked by two regular extractor are same then it should re execute the request and pick one more time or till the values picked are different?

Comment: Is there any other way to pick random values and on next iteration it should not pick the value which is picked in earlier iteration, it should be the other one